# Pandas DF nested loop to find value matching value from loop1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python/pandas.. so please don't judge:)

I have a DF with stock data (i.e., Date, Close Value, ...). 
Now I want to see if a given Close value will hit a target value (e.g. Close+50€, Close-50€).

I wrote a nested loop to check every close value with the following close values of that day:

```
def calc_zv(_df, _distance):
_df['ZV_C'] = 0
_df['ZV_P'] = 0
for i in range(0, len(_df)):
    _date = _df.iloc[i].get('Date')
    target_put = _df.iloc[i].get('Close') - _distance
    target_call = _df.iloc[i].get('Close') + _distance
    for x in range(i, len(_df)-1):
        a = _df.iloc[x+1].get('Close')
        _date2 = _df.iloc[x+1].get('Date')
        if(target_call <= a and _date == _date2):
            _df.ix[i,'ZV_C'] = 1
            break    
        elif(target_put >= a and _date == _date2): 
            _df.ix[i,'ZV_P'] = 1
            break
        elif (_date != _date2):
            break
```

This works fine.. but I wonder if there is a "better" (Faster, more panda-like) solution?

Thanks and best wishes.
M.

## EDIT

hi again,
here is some sample data generator:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PX.indicator_macros import calc_zv
import datetime
abc = datetime.datetime.now()
print(abc)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
                    'Close' : pd.Series(np.random.randn(5000))})

#print(df2.to_string())

calc_zv(df2, 2)

#print(df2.to_string())

abc = datetime.datetime.now()
print(abc)
```

for 5000 rows i need approx. 10s. 
I have stock data for 3 years (in 15min intervall) which takes some minutes.

cheers

Comment: Please post sample data so we can reproduce your code. And what is the performance of current approach?

Comment: hi, i have edited the original post and added some sample data. the overall performance is not too bad, but i guess that there is room for improvement :)

Comment: @Parfait i did (in case u did not see my other post)

Comment: I actually attempted a solution but it seems you compare every row with every row after it. Pretty tough to do without looping.

Comment: @parfait ok thanks. then I will stay with that solution :) any other comparision might result in wrong calculation. thanks and cheers!